# Banding too obvious in radient gradient

Tags: css

I need to create a webpage that looks exactly like the one below:
http://imgur.com/40TiQiY.jpg

What i have currently done:
http://imgur.com/uBaaten.png

```
body {
 background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#EF4747 0%, #7E2424 100%); /* Safari 5.1     to 6.0 */
 background: -o-radial-gradient(#EF4747 0%, #7E2424 100%); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(#EF4747 0%, #7E2424 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */      background: radial-gradient(#EF4747 0%, #7E2424 100%); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

The banding of the radial gradient is too obvious in the second picture. How can  i improve my current code to make it look like the first picture?

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Basically...NO. If there is little difference in the start and end values that's likely what you will get.

Comment: You are not using the correct colors corresponding to the gradient given in first image. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0sLs4z1u/) is a fiddle with the correct colors and it works fine. But as @Paulie_D said, if you intentionally made the colors different and it needs to be as in your code (given in question), then it would be that way only.

Comment: In fact the colors used in your own code produce a smooth gradient only. I think some other piece of code is affecting your gradient. Can you create a full demo so that we can help?

Answer (score 1):

Used some RGB values instead of hex and I hope this is somewhat what you look for.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpNLLJ

```
body {

    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgb(255, 156, 156), rgb(255, 0, 0));
    height: 1000px; 
    width: 1000px
```

}